# Why It Is Printing 4 Times?

Tags: python, loops, nested-loops

Here are my two nested loops in Python. But why is it printing 4 times?

```
links=["/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php", "/wp-admin/install.php"]
f=open('list.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')
for sub_link in range(len(links)):
    sub_link= links[sub_link]
    for line in f:
        line = line.split('/')
        print(line[2]+sub_link)
```

While I only want it printing lenth of my "List.txt" file and List.txt has only two lines.

[image]

Comment: Outer loop runs 2 times, each time it runs, inner loop runs 2 times. 2x2 equals 4.

Comment: You should try `for sub_link in links:`, no need for `range` and `len` and the indexing below.

Comment: @KlausD. The How Will I Increment Index Value Of Array?

Comment: You have not used the index in your code except of retrieving the value. If you need the index use `for index, value in enumerate(your_list):`

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through both arrays at once, you can do this:

```
for link, line in zip(links, f):
  print(line + link)
```

This will only print 2 values, which I assume is what you are trying to do, with output:

```
www.nlpfitnesssolutions.com.au/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php
ethree-asia.com/wp-admin/install.php
```

If you want additional lines in the file to be merged in an alternating pattern, you could do something like this:

```
for i in range(len(f)):
  print(links[i % 2] + f[i])
```

Note that `i % 2` means divide my 2 and take the remainder, so it alternates between 0 and 1.

Comment: No problem! (could you accept this answer and upvote? :) )

Comment: Bro, But When I Increase The List.txt It Doesn't Work :(

Comment: Am Trying To list.txt All Lines With link[] Array lines, Array Has two, But list.txt can be more :(

Comment: How do you want additional lines to be merged with the link array?

Comment: like (line 1 + link[0]) then (line 2 + link[1]), (line 3 + link[0]) again?

Comment: If so, I added to my answer to account for that :)

Comment: Still happy to help if you have questions!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have split the content of your file by '\n', the return is a list of lines in the file.

```
f=open('sample', 'r').read().split('\n') # f is a list of all lines in the file
print(len(f)) # length of the list f is the number of lines in the file
```

I hope this helps

Comment: have a look on My Question , :|

Comment: I thought your question is that you wanted the length of the file. Regarding the unexpected results, @xiaofeng.li already answered this part "Outer loop runs 2 times, each time it runs, inner loop runs 2 times. 2x2 equals 4".

Comment: It is better to include a sample of the file list.txt with the results you are looking for.